# create an matrix of an array from the given string

Tags: javascript

I am trying to create an matrix of array from given string ('bananabar'). each matrix element should have made from taking one string element off at last and append upfront.

for example: first array would be ['b', 'a', 'n', 'a', 'n', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'r'] and  next matrix array would be  ['r','b', 'a', 'n', 'a', 'n', 'a', 'b', 'a'].

Here is my function:

```
function createTable(s) {

      var strArr = s.split('');
      var arr = [];

      for (i=0; i<s.length; i++) {
        arr[i] = strArr;
        console.log(arr[i])
        strArr.unshift(strArr.pop()); 
      }
      console.log(arr, 'arr')
      return arr;
    }
```

when I console logged the arr[i] withing for loop to see if taking one array element from strArr off and append it upfront, and it shows up correct. following is console log statement within for loop.

```
[ 'b', 'a', 'n', 'a', 'n', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'r' ]
[ 'r', 'b', 'a', 'n', 'a', 'n', 'a', 'b', 'a' ]
[ 'a', 'r', 'b', 'a', 'n', 'a', 'n', 'a', 'b' ]
[ 'b', 'a', 'r', 'b', 'a', 'n', 'a', 'n', 'a' ]
[ 'a', 'b', 'a', 'r', 'b', 'a', 'n', 'a', 'n' ]
[ 'n', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'r', 'b', 'a', 'n', 'a' ]
[ 'a', 'n', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'r', 'b', 'a', 'n' ]
[ 'n', 'a', 'n', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'r', 'b', 'a' ]
[ 'a', 'n', 'a', 'n', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'r', 'b' ]
```

however when I console logged returned result it shows following arrays of array:

```
[ [ 'b', 'a', 'n', 'a', 'n', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'r' ],
  [ 'b', 'a', 'n', 'a', 'n', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'r' ],
  [ 'b', 'a', 'n', 'a', 'n', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'r' ],
  [ 'b', 'a', 'n', 'a', 'n', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'r' ],
  [ 'b', 'a', 'n', 'a', 'n', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'r' ],
  [ 'b', 'a', 'n', 'a', 'n', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'r' ],
  [ 'b', 'a', 'n', 'a', 'n', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'r' ],
  [ 'b', 'a', 'n', 'a', 'n', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'r' ],
  [ 'b', 'a', 'n', 'a', 'n', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'r' ] ]
```

but I wanted output in the following way

```
   [ [ 'b', 'a', 'n', 'a', 'n', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'r' ]
    [ 'r', 'b', 'a', 'n', 'a', 'n', 'a', 'b', 'a' ]
    [ 'a', 'r', 'b', 'a', 'n', 'a', 'n', 'a', 'b' ]
    [ 'b', 'a', 'r', 'b', 'a', 'n', 'a', 'n', 'a' ]
    [ 'a', 'b', 'a', 'r', 'b', 'a', 'n', 'a', 'n' ]
    [ 'n', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'r', 'b', 'a', 'n', 'a' ]
    [ 'a', 'n', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'r', 'b', 'a', 'n' ]
    [ 'n', 'a', 'n', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'r', 'b', 'a' ]
    [ 'a', 'n', 'a', 'n', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'r', 'b' ] ]
```

see if you can figure out what's causing the issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason you are having this problem is that you are pushing a reference to the *same* array into your matrix and then altering the same array over and over again. Each time you `push` and `unshift` you are doing it to every row in the matrix because they are all references to the same array.

There are lots of other ways to do this, but to illustrate the problem, here's your original code with one small change. It uses `slice()` to make a copy of the array before pushing into the matrix:

```js
let strArr = ['b', 'a', 'n', 'a', 'n', 'a', 'b', 'a', 'r']
var arr = strArr.slice();

for (i=0; i<strArr.length; i++) {
    arr[i] = strArr.slice(); // copy the array
    strArr.unshift(strArr.pop()); 
 }
 console.log(arr.map(row => row.join(',')))
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a way to do it by using [Array.from()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/from) twice and [String.prototype.charAt()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/charAt):

```js
const makeMatrix = s =>
  Array.from({ length: s.length }, (_, i) =>
    Array.from({ length: s.length }, (_, j) =>
      s.charAt((j - i + s.length) % s.length)));

console.log(JSON.stringify(makeMatrix('bananabar')));
```